# Is it possible to make webpack consume a React components from a package and rebuild the package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, jsx

I'm trying to build an npm package to standardize my layout components that use [geist](https://github.com/geist-org/geist-ui) components at their core. At first, I tried to use the npm package as if it was a local component but it throws a webpack loader error when it tries to read the  component for example:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| const Badged = ({ content }) => {
|     return (
>         <Badge>
|             <b>{content}</b>
|         </Badge>
```

After reading around a bit it seems I need something like `webpack` or `rollup` to build everything to a dist folder in my npm package. How can I set up a pipeline to consume the type data from the source package and build my components to a dist folder?

Comment: Go to https://webpack.js.org/ and read through the landing page and then follow the [getting started](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started) link. If you have **specific** questions after doing all this then you can ask them here.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, Webpack is used as an application bundler while Rollup is used as a library bundler. The reason for this is that, historically, Rollup could produce tree-shakable ESM Module output. Webpack recently added support for ESM output.

The general steps for library development are:

- Setup a bundler like Rollup, etc.
- Configure it to produce both ESM and Common.js output in the dist folder.
- When publishing the package, ensure that `dist` is added to `files` or at least not added to `npmignore` list.
- Always published a compiled code. The `main` or `entry` field should point to the compiled code's entry file.
- When publishing a library, make use of `externals` to exclude all third-party `node_modules` from your bundle so that they are explicitly installed on users side and your library contains only your code. Nearly all bundlers support this feature.